# send multiple request parmeter in get request in curl, only single parameter is going

Tags: unix, curl, get

I am trying to make a curl get request to my api through command line.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/getList?id=100&mrp=50&discount=0
```

But when I log the request in my api I get:

```
&{GET /getList?id=100 HTTP/1.1 1 1  which means that only id is being sent through the request. I don't understand why it is happening.
```

Answer (score 8):

When you run the curl command with multiple request parameters separated by `&`, unix treats the `&` as sign to execute the previous command in the background.Everthing else following it is treated as a separate command.

Wrap the url in quote while sending the request

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/getList?id=100&mrp=50&discount=0"
```

Comment: Didn't look beneath my mouse when I copied/pasted the url, stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the reasons for only **id** getting passed in the Curl Get request:

1. If you see your CURL command, you will notice that you are using `&` to pass multiple values to your request parameters in this GET call/request.

`curl http://localhost:8080/getList?id=100&mrp=50&discount=0`

2. In the Linux/Unix environment, `&` has a pre-defined interpretation. It is used to run any command in the background. So if `&` is present after any text, then the  text is interpreted as a command and & means to run this command in the background.
3. Any text after `&` is treated as a new command. So your above Curl get request is interpreted by Linux as 3 different commands:
   i. `curl http://localhost:8080/getList?id=100&`
   ii. `mrp=50&`
   iii. `discount=0`

**Solution** : The solution to avoid this interpretation by Unix/Linux is to surround your url with double quotes `"`

`curl "http://localhost:8080/getList?id=100&mrp=50&discount=0"`

This will help you pass all the three parameter values to your curl get request.